# Countx where previous row contains specified value

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

In powerpivot i have the following set up.

```
**column1**          **column2**    **column3 (count)**
wiliam              5460aeac1d0f1          2
Chicken             5460aeac1d0f1          2
faces               5460aeac1d0f9          2
massive turtle      5460aeac1d0f9          2
faces               5460aeac1d022          1
massive turtle      5460aeac1d027          1
```

Column 3 is calculated with:

```
 =countx(filter

               ('table',EARLIER('table[Column2])='table[Column2])

        ,'table'[Column2])
```

I want to add a 4th column that does the same, BUT also counts if a previously matched column2 entry also has the column1 entry of massive turtle.

```
**column1**          **column2**    **column3 (count)** **column4 (count)**
wiliam              5460aeac1d0f1          2                 0
Chicken             5460aeac1d0f1          2                 0 
faces               5460aeac1d0f9          2                 1
massive turtle      5460aeac1d0f9          2                 1
faces               5460aeac1d022          1                 0
massive turtle      5460aeac1d027          1                 1
```

I have tried:

```
 =countx(filter('table',EARLIER('table[Column2])='table[Column2] && 
EARLIER('table[Column1])="massive turtle"),'table'[Column2])
```

But this does not count for the rows that have faces in column1 even though they have matching column2 entries where column1 = 'massive turtle'.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Why does the row with `5460aeac1d022` get a `column4` count of 1?

Comment: ah good point, it gets it because of a typo. Thanks will amend

Comment: You changed the last row too now. Why does `5460aeac1d027` not have a count of `1`?

Answer (score 0):

Your function
`=countx(filter('table',EARLIER('table[Column2])='table[Column2] && 
EARLIER('table[Column1])="massive turtle"),'table'[Column2])`

on a first iteration slices the data  to this: :

```
    **column1**          **column2**    **column3 (count)** **column4 (count)**
faces               5460aeac1d0f9          2                 1
massive turtle      5460aeac1d0f9          2                 1
```

because of the value of second column "5460aeac1d0f9" and it counts one time "massive turtle" but the filter applied before was"5460aeac1d0f9", therefore you are getting 1 for these 2 rows from your count function.

therefore  I would suggest something like:

```
=IF('table'[column1]="massive turtle",COUNTX(FILTER('table',EARLIER([column2])='table'[column2] && 'table'[column1]="massive turtle"),'table'[column2]),0)
```

[image: Sample]

Hope that helped